# I want to set relativelayout background as transparent in AlerDilog

Tags: android, transparent

I went to implement popup window so i choose the AlertDialog to do it.

Like the following picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CdmW.png)there are 2 RelativeLayout the one in pink and the one in green they both are in RelativeLayout
I want the white space be transparent as the transparency of AlertDialog

The picture above show once clicking on button in AlertDialog

I tried many things like:

1. in xml file i tried this:
   -background:"android:color/transparent"

   2.to set the background in java :

   - view_layout.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0)));
   - view_layout.setBackgroundColor(android:color/transparent);

     3. tried the transparent theme thing it also go wrong

Need Help

Comment: Can you [edit] this question and make it clear what your [mcve] is, what you are trying to do, and what results you get?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the instruction's how to ASK Question

Comment: I solve it,
it's 
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);